# Method identifier [29] out of range Error

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I have a EJB that existed in Weblogic 10.3. We moved it to 12c and modified the build to use the maven-plugin to create the EJB client and EJB (2 separate builds).

There is a Java application that needs to call the EJB via a remote interface. In doing so, there are 2 methods that give the following error (the rest of the methods work fine):

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Method identifier [29] out of range
    at weblogic.rjvm.BasicOutboundRequest.sendReceive(BasicOutboundRequest.java:108)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ReplicaAwareRemoteRef.invoke(ReplicaAwareRemoteRef.java:290)
    at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ReplicaAwareRemoteRef.invoke(ReplicaAwareRemoteRef.java:248)
    at net.footware.shoeManager.ShoeManager_xwmvzk_EOImpl_1211_WLStub.updateShoeStatus(Unknown Source)
```

The other method gives the same error, but with a different number:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Method identifier [28] out of range
```

It's notable that the client jar and EJB jar is built in 2 different pom.xml files. The pom.xml that builds the client explicitly excludes some classes, while the pom.xml that builds the EJB jar does not.

It's not simply missing the method as that would send back a "Method Not Found" error. I also reduced the method to simply returning true (no other logic). It appears the call never reaches the code in the remote methods. There are other methods that take and return the same objects and don't throw errors.

When I created a new method that accepts a boolean value, I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 04
```

Any idea what could cause these errors?

Comment: What are the signature of the methods? What is you EJB version? Are you sure that there is no problems in serializing parameters? Can you deploy them as local beans and call local methods?